# Hide files without attributes

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I hide files without using the file attributes?

---

I use [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) to synchronize a desktop, but this creates a few files and a folder I don't want to see.

I managed to hide most of them by marking them as protected system files with `attrib +S +H`, but the attributes on `.SyncID` are always reset to hidden only.

Synchronizing an outer directory isn't possible because of the way [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/?lang=en) handles desktop folders and I'd like to avoid hiding hidden files.

Comment: I worked around the problem for now by symlinking Dexpot's desktop directory to a subfolder in a synchronized directory. It should be possible to create a general solution for making files unlisted in specific programs with a file system minifilter, but unfortunately I don't know enough C to implement that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide a file in Windows 7 and you are the administrator, right click on the file or folder.  Then click on the properties option.  Under the general tab, there will be an attributes section.  Check the box that says "Hidden".  If it is a folder you are hiding, it will ask if you want to hide folders and sub-directories.  Make the appropriate choice that you want.

EDIT:  You can also use third party tools to hide files like [FileLocker](http://www.filelocker.com/) or [FolderLock](http://download.cnet.com/Folder-Lock/3000-2092_4-10063343.html).  There is also a method of using the file extensions to hide the file [here](http://readmenow.net/hide-files-windows-file-extensions/), but I have never tried it, so I am not sure how effective it is.

Comment: I don't want to hide all hidden files. The file is already marked as hidden and I can't change the attributes to include system as explained above. This question is about finding a different way.

Comment: O, yea sorry I should have read the question more carefully.  I edited my question to use a few other alternative ways to hide files.

Comment: The addition is even farther beside the point though...

Comment: The only question asked is this, _How can I hide files without using the file attributes?_ Perhaps you should rephrase the question because I guess I am not understanding what you are asking.

Comment: The links you posted only deal with encrypting or renaming a file. If you read the whole question text you will see that I probably can't move the file. I'm really just asking for a method to _hide_ the file in Windows Explorer that does _exactly that_. I know this question is a bit narrow, if you have a workaround that solves my problem but doesn't answer the question feel free to post it as comment.